# Trying to add 9 digit comma separated numbers in excel sheet row manually

Tags: excel

I am trying to add comma separated numbers in excel like

```
103005703,103020000,000000000,000000000,000000000,000000000
103005703,103020000,000000000,000000000,000000000,000000000
103005703,103020000,000000000,000000000,000000000,000000000
103005703,103020000,000000000,000000000,000000000,000000000
103005703,103020000,000000000,000000000,000000000,000000000
```

I am doing this manually(there is no other way for me) but they keep on changing like this

```
103,005,703,103,020,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
103,005,703,103,020,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
103,005,703,103,020,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
103,005,703,103,020,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
103,005,703,103,020,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

I have to upload this excel file in a tool, but the tool can only understand 9 digit comma-separated values (the numbers are employee IDs)

Is there any way anyone can think of, please suggest

Thanks,
Nakul

Comment: I don't get it, are you just pasting an entire line into a single cell, or is each number going into a separate cell?

Comment: Just a guess: I think by "add" OP means "enter" comma separated numbers into a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the cells are being auto-formatted as numbers. Try changing the format of the cells to text, and then pasting (or typing) the employee IDs in... you may have to select "match destination formatting" if pasting in.